# Eclipse - how to turn off dynamic compilation/error checking

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I have problem with Eclipse with Scala plugin, it's run very slow becouse of dynamic checking of the code. Is it possible to turn it of? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of turning off automatic build, you can also try and tweak your eclipse config file. You will find useful information here : http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Setup.

In my case, with the provided hints, I've finally obtained a stable configuration of eclipse for scala.

Answer (score 2):

Project -> Build automatically

Comment: Nicolas' wiki link is useful. I had some major performance problems (old macbook) with the plugin. My current eclipse.ini https://gist.github.com/771600

Answer (score 0):

it seems you installed EQUINOX WEAVING LAUNCHER plugin
this makes your ide very slow