# Can I avoid compiling sources twice when running play2 and eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

Currently I am running eclipse and play (with ~run) at the same time. When I change a file it will be compiled by play and by eclipse.

Is it possible to avoid one of those two compilation steps?

As far as I know, the eclipse plugin also uses sbt to build the project so maybe there is a way to execute the play "run" command inside eclipse?

(I am asking because my laptop is not very fast and compilation takes some time, and I would like to have the "Fast turnaround" as advertised on the play webpage ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803283/eclipse-how-to-turn-off-dynamic-compilation-error-checking

Comment: hm, I don't think it is a duplicate question. I do not want to turn off the features of eclipse - if I wanted that I could just use a text editor.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn off `Build Automatically` from the `Project` menu without losing any of the IDE functionality. Binaries will be built only by Sbt (on the command line).

A detailed guide for setting-up Play 2 with Scala IDE can be found on the Scala IDE website: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html

Comment: When I turn this off I am loosing some functionality which is important for me: When I change something in one file and this breaks other files I do not see this directly.

Comment: Try pointing the Eclipse build path the place where Play/SBT is building.

Comment: @pedrofurla: tried. Didn't help -- Play still wants to compile sources that Eclipse has already compiled, and Eclipse wants to compile them itself or it won't show/remove cross-file errors.

Comment: Oh, remove Build Automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet tried to run the play run sbt task in eclipse.

BUT you can run the server directly from eclipse.

1. Add "target/scala-2.9.1/classes" to your class path, use filters to include only your assets. (Project Properties, Java Build Path)
2. Choose "Run Configurations..." from the Run-Button-Menu.
3. Create a new "Java Application" configuration with your favourite name.
4. Main Tab: Use "DebugStart" as your main class
5. Arguments Tab: Configure any "-Dconfig.file=..." "-Dlogger.file" options you might need in VM arguments
6. Classpath Tab: Add the conf directory to the classpath (Advanced/Add Folders)

Create DebugStart.scala with:

```
import play.core.server.NettyServer
import java.io.File
import play.core.SBTLink
import play.core.TestApplication
import play.api.test.FakeApplication
import play.api.test.TestServer

object DebugStart {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val app = FakeApplication()
    val server = TestServer(9000, app)
    server.start()
  }
}
```

You can now start the app with run or debug. If you use debug, you can perform some code changes without any restart.

My version of DebugStart.scala actually contains some platform dependent hackish code to kill any running process, so that I can just hit F11 or CTRL+F11 to restart the application.

To ensure that your assets/sources are up to date run:

```
> sbt
...
[your project] $  ~ ;play-copy-assets;sources
```

Comment: After adjusting configuration, play is running in Eclipse and listening on port 9000, but it doesn't work: the console view remains blank (unless there is a configuration error or I request a thread dump) and if I point my browser to localhost:9000, it just hangs waiting for a connection. I just can't imagine why. ¿Hints?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea 12 (Leda) is coming soon. I'm using 11 for a while and there's no such problems but new version will offer much better Play 2.0 integration.